# wordpress get menu id by custom post_type?

Tags: custom-post-types, menus

I'm trying to figure out how to get a menu id by it's post_type, is that possible? I need to get the menuid of my post_type 'events', but I'm not sure how. If anyone could help that would be great.

Comment: What do you mean by "menu id"?

Comment: I have a custom post_type called "events", and in my menu I've added in Events as a page. 

This displays a list of events, when I click on a post, it takes me to the article page of the event. 

I'm trying to get the ID of the main list page Events inside the article page. But I can't use get_page_by_title as there are language files so it's not always called "Events". If that makes sense?

Comment: Have you tried getting page by slug
`$page = get_page_by_path( 'events' );
echo get_the_title( $page );`

Comment: If your post type is set up correctly, there is no page for the list of events. Instead there's an "archive". To get the URL of the archive use `get_post_type_archive_link( 'events' );`.